# Setting state in useEffect hook does not change state value

Tags: reactjs, react-native, use-state

am writing an app in react native and i got a problem with useState and useEffect hooks. I would like to change increment state value by one every 10 seconds.

Here is my code:

```
const [tripDistance, setTripDistance] = useState(0);

useEffect(() => {
  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    setTripDistance((prevState) => prevState + 1);

    console.log(tripDistance);
  }, 10000);
  return () => {
    clearInterval(interval);
  };
}, []);
```

but the output from the console.log is always 0.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Setstate is asynchronous, you can't get value directly after setstate. For example after console.log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output is always zero because in your `useEffect` you are not listening for the changes on `tripDistance` state. When you call `setTripDistance` you cannot access the updated value immediately.

You should add another `useEffect` that listen on `tripDistance` in order to have the correct console.log.

So you have to do something like:

```
const [tripDistance, setTripDistance] = useState(0);

useEffect(() => {
  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    setTripDistance((prevState) => prevState + 1);
  }, 10000);
  return () => {
    clearInterval(interval);
  };
}, []);
useEffect(() => console.log(tripDistance), [tripDistance]);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
const [tripDistance, setTripDistance] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setTripDistance((prevState) => prevState + 1);
    }, 10000);
    return () => {
      clearInterval(interval);
    };
  }, [tripDistance]);
```